# Multidimensional array in pdf report using codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, mpdf

Below is the code snippet for printing values in a PDF report using codeigniter.

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $getData)
                {

                $html1 = $this->load->view('pdf/pod2', $getData, true);

                //echo $html;exit;
                $this->load->library('pdf');
                $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
                $pdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
                $pdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';

                //$pdf->SetFooter($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'|{PAGENO}|'.date(DATE_RFC822));
                $pdf->WriteHTML($html1);
                                }
```

If i do `echo '<pre>';print_r($data);exit;`

I get the following output

```
    Array
(
    [316] => Array
        (
            [CNote] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Consignment_Details_id] => 316

                )

            [Invoice_Nos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [invoice] => 161052
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [invoice] => 161053
                        )

                )

            [Invoice_Copies] => Array
                (
                )

            [CNote_data] => Array
                (
                )

            [no_packages] => 0
            [driver] => 
        )

    [317] => Array
        (
            [CNote] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Consignment_Details_id] => 317

                )

            [Invoice_Nos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [invoice] => 161066
                        )

                )

            [Invoice_Copies] => Array
                (
                )

            [CNote_data] => Array
                (
                )

            [no_packages] => 0
            [driver] => 
        )

    [318] => Array
        (
            [CNote] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Consignment_Details_id] => 318

                )

            [Invoice_Nos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [invoice] => 161067
                        )

                )

            [Invoice_Copies] => Array
                (
                )

            [CNote_data] => Array
                (
                )

            [no_packages] => 0
            [driver] => 
        )

)
```

Now the problem is in the pdf report only the last array values is being displayed

i.e `318`

Actual scenario what i need is o display three array values but only last value is getting displayed. How to solve this, any help appreciated.

Comment: I dont know which library are you using, but i beleive the $pdf->WriteHTML($html1); is rendering the final PDF.since this statement is with in the foreach you will get - only the final array results in the pdf

Comment: I am using mpdf

Comment: you are assigning single array to view and rending output. You need to assign whole array to view, then write statement